# How to consolidate the dataframe of matching indices and splitting other columns?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, dictionary, data-science

I have a dataframe which needs to be consolidated for same ids and split other columns to different columns as such. I have presented the example input dataframe and required output dataframe.

**Input dataframe example**

```
data = {'id':[1, 1, 1, 2, 2, 2], 
    'status':[3, 3, 3, 4, 4, 4],
    'amount':[30, 40, 50, 60, 70, 80],
    'paid':[100, 200, 300, 400, 500, 600]}

dataframe = pd.DataFrame(data)


   id status amount paid
0   1   3    30     100
1   1   3    40     200
2   1   3    50     300
3   2   4    60     400
4   2   4    70     500
5   2   4    80     600
```

Required output dataframe

```
   id   status  amount_1 amount_2 amount_3 paid_1 paid_2 paid_3
0   1    3       30       40       50       100    200    300
1   2    4       60       70       80       300    400    600
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Does the following achieve what you are after?

**Reproduce your example**

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

data = {'id':[1, 1, 1, 2, 2, 2], 
    'status':[3, 3, 3, 4, 4, 4],
    'amount':[30, 40, 50, 60, 70, 80],
    'paid':[100, 200, 300, 400, 500, 600]}

dataframe = pd.DataFrame(data)
```

output:

[image]

**Step 1: Create index within each group, and set index of dataframe**

```
dataframe['group_id'] = dataframe.groupby('id')['id'].transform(lambda x: np.arange(1,len(x)+1))
dataframe.set_index(['id', 'group_id'], append=False, inplace=True)
```

Now the dataframe looks like:

[image]

**Step 3: Unstack on the group index**

```
dataframe = dataframe.unstack(level=-1)
```

Now the dataframe looks like:

[image]

**Final step: Flatten the column names to match your desired output, and drop extra status columns**

```
dataframe.columns = [f"{x}_{y}" for x,y in dataframe.columns]
dataframe.drop(['status_2', 'status_3'], axis=1, inplace=True)
dataframe.rename({'status_1': 'status'}, axis=1, inplace=True)
```

Giving final form:

[image]